# An question of remove function of a LinkedList implementation in Python

Tags: python

I am writing an implementation of `LinkedList` in Python. In the `remove` function, the function removes items by index. I find an issue of `local variable is not used` when I am removing the first node in the list:

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self, nodes=None):
        self.head = None

    def remove(self, index):
        pre_node = self.head
        if index == 0:
            self.head = self.head.next
            # next line doesn't work
            # pre_node = self.head.next 
            return
        for idx, cur_node in enumerate(self):
            if idx == index-1:
                pre_node = cur_node
            if idx == index:
                pre_node.next = cur_node.next
                return
        raise Exception('index out of range')

    def __iter__(self):  
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            yield node
            node = node.next

    def __str__(self):
        node = self.head
        nodes = []
        while node is not None:
            nodes.append(node.data)
            node = node.next
        nodes.append("None")
        return '->'.join(nodes)

    class Node:
        def __init__(self, data):
            self.data = data
            self.next = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    first_list = LinkedList()
    first_node = LinkedList.Node('0')
    first_list.head = first_node
    second_node = LinkedList.Node('1')
    first_node.next = second_node
    third_node = LinkedList.Node('2')
    second_node.next = third_node
    first_list.remove(0)
    print(first_list)
```

Assuming the list is kind of `0->1->2->None`, when calling `a_list.remove(0)`, it should return `1->2->None`. The code above with the statement `self.head = self.head.next` works well, and `self.head = pre_node.next` works well too, but `pre_node = pre_node.next` and `pre_node = self.head.next` failed with the `pre_node is not used`, and the function returns the original list. I am confused why the code should only be correct with `self.head` on the left hand side of the assignment rather than `pre_node` even we make `pre_node = self.head` before that.

Comment: How exactly do you create the list? Note that `remove` will fail if `self.head` starts as `None`. It also fails if `self.head.next` is `None`, as that causes `self.head` to become `None` before attempting to set `pre_node`. Finally, what do you plan to do if `index` is anything *other* than 0? There needs to be a loop or recursion of some kind.

Comment: Assigning `pre_node` immediately before you return doesn't do anything, hence the warning.  But you've already done the thing you need to do, which is changing `self.head`.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking here. Are you trying to solve the `index > 0` case? Show the code you're trying to use for it! We can't debug code that you only vaguely allude to in comments. `pre_node` is a local variable, so assigning to it just before `return`ing isn't going to achieve much.

Comment: The "local variable is not used" message is just junk spewed out by IDEs like pycharm - it's not a python error, and it doesn't mean the code isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A local variable (like `pre_node`) only exists until you `return` from the function.  So in this code:

```
            self.head = self.head.next
            pre_node = self.head.next 
            return
```

the line `pre_node = self.head.next` does nothing useful, because you're setting a variable that goes away as soon as you return.  This won't actually cause your program to fail, but linters and IDEs will warn you when they see things like this because it's an indication that you missed something (like you meant to make this an instance variable, or you meant to do something else with this value).

In this case, you've already done the thing you need to do to remove the node, which is to reassign `self.head`.  Since the `pre_node = self.head.next` line does nothing, you can remove it without changing how the program works.  There's no real problem here (at least for the `index == 0` case).

The place where a local variable would be useful would be as a way to reference some other node in the list that you need to modify.  For example:

```
def remove(self, index):
    """Remove the node with the given index.
    Raises AttributeError if the index is out of range."""
    if index == 0:
        # Move self.head pointer up one to remove head node.
        self.head = self.head.next
        return
    # Find node before the one with the given index.
    pre_node = self.head
    for _ in range(index-1):
        pre_node = pre_node.next
    # Remove pre_node.next by skipping over it.
    pre_node.next = pre_node.next.next
```

In this code, `pre_node` references a specific node in the list, which you're modifying by reassigning `pre_node.next`.  The variable `pre_node` itself doesn't matter after the function finishes, but the node that it references is a part of the list, so reassigning `pre_node.next` has an effect on the list in a way that reassigning `pre_node` on its own does not.